# Playing video in Gmail

Tags: android, video, gmail, 3gp

I have attached audio or video for my app.when i open my mail, i received audio or video.But my problem is when i got a audio i can find two options play and download in gmail and when i tried for video i can able to find only download option where video had attached..i want to have play option like audio.. Here is my code

```
try {                   
                    String fun1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/hi.3gp";
                    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    sharingIntent.setType("email/text");

                    sharingIntent.setType("video/3gp");

                    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                            Uri.parse("file://" + fun1));
                    String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
                    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
                    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Send via"));

                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```